# A strange scenario in anaconda -- Error while an attempt to launch Spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSGE.png)

I met this error while an attempt to launch Spyder.

Why?

Any replies to solution of this error will be grateful.

Error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 128, in main
from spyder.config.manager import CONF
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 22, in
from spyder.config.main import CONF_VERSION, DEFAULTS, NAME_MAP
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\main.py", line 19, in
from spyder.config.fonts import MEDIUM, SANS_SERIF
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\fonts.py", line 14, in
from spyder.config.utils import is_ubuntu
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\utils.py", line 17, in
from spyder_kernels.utils import iofuncs
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\utils\iofuncs.py", line 34, in
from spyder_kernels.py3compat import getcwd, pickle, PY2, to_text_string
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356
c exec(code, globals, locals)
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

None.
But I will google it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved.

The first try:
After I reset the Spyder with the command in Anaconda Prompt.

spyder --reset

then restarted Anaconda Navigator.
The issue is NOT solved.

The second try:
After that, I read the error messages carefully.
I found that there is and indentation error in

C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py, line 356 c exec(code, globals, locals) ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Then I open the
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py"
with VSC (Visual Studio Code)
Then modify the line in the file.

c exec(code, globals, locals)

to

exec(code, globals, locals)

Save it and restart Anaconda Navigator.
Then the issue is solved.

I think the reason is that, with no purpose, I modify the line

exec(code, globals, locals)

to

c exec(code, globals, locals)